# Window menu is not hidden when using unity session in 17.10

Tags: 17.10, window

I switched from the Gnome desktop environment to Unity in Ubuntu 17.10. However, them menus of some application remain visible at all times (e.g. the calculator, gimp, gnome terminal and more).

See the attached image.

How can I remove them?

[image]